# Путь к файлу с переменным именем из gs для отправки ботом в телеграмм

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-spreadsheet

Имею таблицу, по которой бот отправляет в чат название элемента и файл к нему. Условно, имя указано в ячейке A2, название файла в B2. Например, название файла в ячейке B2 будет example1.pdf.
Файл лежит в относительной директории docs. Я хочу, чтобы после отправки в чат имени элемента из ячейки A2 бот смотрел название файла в ячейке B2 и отправлял его.
Вот код, которым я пытаюсь это сделать

```
nrow=2
ncourse=sh.worksheet("coursesheet").get('A'+str(nrow))
docfile=sh.worksheet("coursesheet").get('B'+str(nrow))
f = open('docs/'+str(docfile),"rb")
bot.send_message(message.chat.id,ncourse)
bot.send_document(message.chat.id,f)
```

Но я получаю ошибку FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "docs/[['example1.pdf']]"
При этом, если я просто заранее напишу

```
docfile="docs/example1.pdf"
f = open(docfile,"rb")
```

то все работает.
Как мне правильно форматировать текст из ячейки B2 в путь к файлу?

Comment: достань значение из ячейки

Comment: Если вы о том, чтобы писать путь в ячейку и использовать его, то тоже не выходит:
В ячейке docs/course1.pdf
docfile=sh.worksheet("coursesheet").get('B'+str(nrow))
f = open(str(docfile),"rb")
bot.send_document(message.chat.id,f)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "[['docs/course1.pdf']]"

Comment: нет, я о том что достать строку из ячейки нужно

Comment: Помогло обращение к ячейке напрямую, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

В общем, необходимо обратиться к ячейке напрямую

```
docfile=sh.worksheet("coursesheet").acell('B'+str(nrow)).value
f = open(str(docfile),"rb")
bot.send_document(message.chat.id,f)
```